# can't use android emulator - qt library not found

Tags: android, ionic-framework

when running `ionic cordova emulate android` in my ionic app I keep getting the errors:

```
No emulator specified, defaulting to thename

[139651052451648]:ERROR:android/android-emu/android/qt/qt_setup.cpp:28:Qt library not found at ../emulator/lib64/qt/lib
Could not launch '/opt/android-sdk/tools/../emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-i386': No such file or directory
Waiting for emulator to start...
```

I don't really see what the problem here is since I have no understanding on the environment of Android SDK. Why should the qt lib be missing and how do I add it properly?